# PHP + MySQL Slow results using while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I made a fast MYSQL based news feed to my website where I'm writing out the last four news from the database with a while function + fetch_arry.. As I remember it worked fine when I used a script like this, but with this one I'm getting horribly slow results from my code up to 18-20 secounds which isn't the best thing for my followers.. what causes the problem or how can I speed the fetching up?

```
$e = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM hirek ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4');
if (!$e) {  
  die(mysql_error());  
  $count = 0; 
  }
$get_hir = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hirek ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4"));
if ($get_hir <= 0)
{
echo '<div class="lil-box lil-box-tl"><div><center><h4>Nincsennek hírek!</h4></center></div></div>';
} else {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($e))  
{
echo '<div class="lil-box lil-box-tl">';
  echo '<h4>'.$row['cim'].'</h4>';
  if($row['kep'] == 0)
  {
  echo '<div class="icon"><img alt="" src="images/icon-info.png" width="24" /></div>';
  } else if($row['kep'] == 1) {
  echo '<div class="icon"><img alt="" src="images/icon-up.png" width="24" /></div>';
  } else if($row['kep'] == 2) {
  echo '<div class="icon"><img alt="" src="images/icon-euro.png" width="24" /></div>';
  }
  echo tores($row['post'],65);
  echo '</div>';

}
}
```

('tores' is a strlen function.)

Comment: Why are you executing `'SELECT * FROM hirek ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4'` twice? Change `$get_hir = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hirek ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4"));` to `$get_hir = mysql_num_rows($e);`

Answer (score 0):

Create index for the field you are sorting on (one time query)

```
ALTER TABLE `hirek`
ADD INDEX `date` (`date`);
```

That should make your query work on the index therefore being a bit faster.

Also rewrite your code to:

```
$e = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM hirek ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4');
if (!$e) {  
 die(mysql_error());  
 $count = 0; 
}
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($e))  $rows[] = $row;

if (count($rows) == 0) {
echo '<div class="lil-box lil-box-tl"><div><center><h4>Nincsennek hírek!</h4></center></div></div>';
} else {
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo '<div class="lil-box lil-box-tl">';
        echo '<h4>'.$row['cim'].'</h4>';
        if($row['kep'] == 0)
        {
            echo '<div class="icon"><img alt="" src="images/icon-info.png" width="24" /></div>';
        }
        else if($row['kep'] == 1) {
            echo '<div class="icon"><img alt="" src="images/icon-up.png" width="24" /></div>';
        } else if($row['kep'] == 2) {
            echo '<div class="icon"><img alt="" src="images/icon-euro.png" width="24" /></div>';
        }
        echo tores($row['post'],65);
        echo '</div>';
      }
}
```

This is one (of many) ways to do that without twice executing the queries.
Also consider switching to mysqli/pdo as mysql_* are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, now it's a bit faster, but it still takes 7-8 secs to load. But anyway, that's better than 20 secs, so.. Thanks ^^ Any more idea?

Comment: I have edited the answer - try it now. Of course the idea from Mark Barker is also good.